# Modelica print current time

Tags: datetime, modelica

How can I print the current date and/or time to a file (e.g. log file, or csv file) from Modelica? Do I need external code for this? I was not able to find any example code in the Modelica Standard Library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print.html

You would need to add this to your equation or algorithm section:

```
.Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print(String(time));
```

For local system time use:
https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime.html

```
model GetTime
  Integer ms;
  Integer sec;
  Integer min;
  Integer hour;
  Integer mday;
  Integer mon;
  Integer year;
algorithm
  (ms, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year) := .Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime();
  .Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("ms:" + String(ms) + "\n");
  .Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("sec:" + String(sec) + "\n");
  .Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("min:" + String(min) + "\n");
  .Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("hour:" + String(hour) + "\n");
  .Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("mday:" + String(mday) + "\n");
  .Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("mon:" + String(mon) + "\n");
  .Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("year:" + String(year) + "\n");
end GetTime;
```

Comment: The tool (Dymola) I am using returns the correct time, except for the year. The Integer I get for year is 10. Is that expected?

Comment: I get the same in OpenModelica, seems to be a bug.

Comment: The C code for getTime is defined here:
https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/blob/master/Modelica/Resources/C-Sources/ModelicaInternal.c#L1264

Comment: I opened an MSL bug about it: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/issues/3143

Comment: I replied there as well. Today is 2019-10-10, and the "month" above is actually the day in the month. You get ...hour, monthDay, month, year as results.

Comment: My bad, sorry for this, I corrected the call to getTime() now.

Answer (score 3):

Since v1.1 the Testing library (shipped with Dymola 2019) contains the operator record `DateTime`.

There are several constructors for the operator record. If no further arguments are given, the system time is used. Here is an example:

```
> dt =Testing.Utilities.Time.DateTime()   // use getTime() to create the operator record
> dt.a                                    // access one of the variables of the operator record
= 2019
> String(dt)                              // convert to string using default format
= "2019-10-14 12:31:50"
> String(dt, format="%Hh %MINmin %Ss")    // convert to string using custom format
= "12h 35min 12s"
```

`Durations` is another operator record in the Testing library, which can deal with time spans.

Comment: How can I load the Testing library from a .mos script? Do I need to use the full path to the  subfolder in Dymola installation directory?

Comment: Use the command `DymolaCommands.SimulatorAPI.openModelFile("Testing")`.